# Getting CORS/Content-type issues with Google Cloud Run and Firebase

Tags: firebase, cors, grpc, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have a gRPC server running on Google Cloud Run and a React web app hosted on Firebase. the web app makes requests using Web gRPC. I followed the guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run but I can't get the function to work - I either get this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://app-id.firebaseapp.com/{service}/{method}' from origin 'https://{app-id}.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

when I use the server at `https://{app-id}.firebase.com` as my service host, or

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2850 FAILED GRPC REQUEST
message: Unknown Content-type received.
```

using the other host name (`https://{app-id}.web.app`).

This should work according to the guide, I can't figure out why it's not. I tried messing with the headers (all kinds of stuff with Access-Control-Allow-Origin) but didn't get anwyhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole [book](https://livebook.manning.com/book/cors-in-action) about it ...while you need to send origin `https://{app-id}.web.app` back in a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://{app-id}.web.app` header, in order to permit the embed. Something alike this ...depending where and what you'd like to embed:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    ...
    "headers": [{
      "source" : "https://{app-id}.web.app",
      "headers" : [{
        "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value" : "https://{app-id}.web.app"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Weirdly, I still get that last message about the content type :(

Comment: Also idk if this is relevant but my hit count on the Run dashboard has stayed zero this entire time, meaning it can't even hit the actual service.

Answer (score -1):

After digging a bunch more: it's a browser thing, there needs to be proxy between the browser and the gRPC server for this to work :(.